# Github REST API to know all my activities filtered by date

Tags: rest, github, github-api, pull-request

I would like to know

- the list of PRs i reviewed
- List of PRs i created

in the given date range

I was able to get some information
i would create personal token as explained in https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods

I was able to get whole lot of json from below API
from https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity

but not sure how to filter them by date range and types of events i need.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Note that git itself doesn't even have the notion of a pull-request (nor a REST API). You're asking about the *Github API*. I've tweaked the tags for you, but thought that you should be aware of the difference.